# How to download a web page as a PDF using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, download, html

I want to make a script that can download a website as a PDF. the user should be able to enter a URL (https://stackoverflow.com/) and a file path for the PDF to download to (c:\Bob\PDF).

This is my code so far:

```
import requests
import pdfkit

url = input("Please enter the url of the file you want to download.")
pdf = pdfkit.from_url(url, "file.pdf")
path = input("Please enter the file path that you would like the file to 
download to. c:\Bob\PDF is an example of a valid file path.")

print("Download starting.")
r = requests.get(pdf)

with open(path, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

For some reason, the PDF doesn't download. I think I need to first convert the web page to HTML, and then convert it to a PDF so it can download, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yep. There are several popular packages that can convert `html` to `pdf`. Take a look at `wkhtmltopdf`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all method

```
from_url from module 'pdfkit'
```

returns `True` when called.

After executing this line `pdf = pdfkit.from_url(url, "file.pdf")` value of `pdf` is `True` or `False` depending on downloading and creating the file.

So this line 
`r = requests.get(pdf)` 
is evalueated to 
`r = requests.get(True)`
Which cannot be executed properly.

Basically you only need to ask the user for url and path to the file

```
url = input("Please enter the url of the file you want to download.")
path = input("Please enter the file path ex. C:\Jim\Desktop")
file_name = input("Please enter file name")
if pdfkit.from_url(str(url), str(path + file_name)): # Check if method from_url returned True
    print("Sucessfully created pdf from url")
else:
    print("Something went wrong")
```